# summation methode of Fejér

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, summation, exponential-sum, fejer-kernel

let's define $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ a $2\pi$ periodic continuous function.

Let's say $s_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n} f\hat (k) e^{ikx}$.

Let's say $t_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} s_{k}(x)$.

Prove that $t_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n} \frac{n-|k|+1}{n+1} f\hat (k) e^{ikx}$

my attempt: $t_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} s_{k}(x) = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=-k}^{k} f\hat (l) e^{ilx}$. Now I tried different things with the sommations and switch them, but i always got stuck with my $k,n,l$. Is there someone who can bekome $t_{n}(x)$ and explain me why you can switch the sommations?

Comment: The $x$ is missing on the right-hand side of the statement you like to prove. Also, what is $l$ in that statement?

Comment: I think I accedently changed my x into an l, does it make more sense now?

Comment: I rewrote my $s_{k}(x)=\sum_{l=-k}^{k}f\hat (l) e^{ilx}$ that's where my $l$ comes from

Comment: I guess $\hat f(x)$ should be $\hat f(k)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: You have to prove that $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\sum\limits_{\ell  =  - k}^k {\hat f(\ell )e^{i\ell x} } }  = \sum\limits_{k =  - n}^n {(n - \left| k \right| + 1)\hat f(k)e^{ikx} } .
$$ Just look at how many times $\hat f(\ell )e^{i\ell x} $ appear on the left-hand side for a given $\ell$.

Comment: Yes so far I know what to prove, but I really can't see where the n en |k| comes from in the right side of your equation?

Comment: Write out the left-hand side for small $n$ ($n=2$ or $3$, say) term-by-term and make an observation about how many times a particular term appear.

Comment: yes, i did it for n=2. But I really think I do something wrong. I got then $\sum_{k=0}^{2}\sum_{l=-k}^{k} f \hat (l) e^{ilx}$

Comment: when I write tis out I don't get anything in function of k, i still keep having it in function of l

Comment: Write it out completely using the meaning of summation for each particular $k$ and $l$, term-by-term. E.g., $$
\hat f(0)e^{i0x}  + (\hat f( - 1)e^{i( - 1)x}  + \hat f(0)e^{i0x}  + \hat f(1)e^{i(1)x} ) +  \cdots .
$$ See how many times $\hat f(0)e^{i0x} $ occur and so on.

Comment: alright thank you, I will write it more out. :)